# Twitter - automatic aggregation of replies to an account - OAuth problem

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, basic-authentication

We have a company twitter account. We have 6 members. I wanted the 6 members to be able to tweet from their accounts and we aggregate it and show it at our site if the tweet is about the company (it basically shows "Whats happening").

I created a company twitter account, and members will reply to the company twitter account, when its a company tweet.

I used the twitter.lib.php API. I coded it and when I tried to run it, I got the message "Basic Authentication is not supported". Looking around, I guess twitter uses OAuth now. From what I have seen, there has to be an authentication at the twitter site and then it'll send me back to my site. However this will not work for me, I want an automated bot updating our site. What can I do now? Thanks!

Comment: There is a way to do authentication via OAuth without a human involved, you just need to have your OAuth secret, access key, and access token from the API settings of your application.

Comment: +1 @Amber: Thanks for your reply. Yea, that was it. I found an article explaining it in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have searched a bit more! For anyone else interested in the answer:
http://masnun.me/2010/04/30/setting-up-twitter-bots-with-oauth.html

**Edit:** Link updated

Comment: @Jeff: I am a little surprised that you have down voted me for this. The link was active when I posted it, which was 4 months ago. It is impossible to guarantee all links posted will be active forever.

Comment: @Aishwar - It was nothing personal. I'm not down-voting you, I'm down-voting the link. It is no longer an answer to the question. I'm not sure how else "bad" answers are to be resolved. SO uses voting to indicate if answers are relevant or not. Would you like for me to re-up-vote it to 0? Let me know and I will.

Comment: @Aishwar +1 @Jeff a 2s google search with "setting-up-twitter-bots-with-oauth" gave me the active http://www.masnun.me/2010/04/30/setting-up-twitter-bots-with-oauth.html

Comment: @brian_d: Thanks for the link. Have updated the original answer with it.